# SELECT then UPDATE all rows from RESULTSET

Tags: java, sql, mysql

I am wanting to update all the rows in the `RESULTSET` from the `SELECT` in one single `UPDATE` query.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT id_queue, status FROM table WHERE status IN (0,2) ORDER BY status, id_queue ASC FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE table SET status = 97 WHERE id_queue= " + id_combined + ";
```

So, I guess I need to take all the `id_queue` ids, put them together like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` into `id_combined`.

Any idea the best way to do this in JAVA?

NOTE: I am not just trying to update all with status 0 & 2 to 97, I want to use the select resultset somewhere else.

Comment: If you need to update all and get the result set have you considered a stored procedure to do the update and then return the records updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what SQL dialect you are using, but this is worth a try:

```
update table set status = 97 where ID_queue in
(SELECT id_queue FROM table WHERE status IN (0,2))
```

Comment: That will definitely be the fastest approach

Comment: Doesn't work in MySQL though as per comment on DGH's answer posted at roughly the same. (Although it can if you wrap it all up in a derived table)

Comment: One thing is missing - the OP requested to have a resultset of the records being updated.

Answer (score 2):

**Use a `StringBuilder` to collect the id numbers returned in the `ResultSet`, and then use this to build an update query.**

First, execute the query and collect the ID's.

```
StringBuilder ids = new StringBuilder();

Statement statement = this.conn.createStatement();
statement.executeQuery("SELECT id_queue, status FROM table WHERE status IN (0,2) ORDER BY status, id_queue ASC;");
ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
  if (ids.length() > 0)
    ids.append(',');
  ids.append(rs.getInt("id_queue"));
}

// use the resultset for whatever else you want

rs.close();
```

Then, perform the update.

```
if (ids.length() > 0) {
  statement = this.conn.createStatement();
  statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE table SET status = 97 WHERE id_queue In ("+ids.toString()+");");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do this is a nested query.  That is, you can put a SELECT inside your UPDATE sort of like this:

```
UPDATE table SET status = 97 WHERE id_queue IN (SELECT id_queue
                                                FROM table
                                                WHERE status IN(0,2))
```

Google for sql 'nested query' or 'subquery' for more info.

Comment: is that going to give me a resultset of which rows it updated?

Comment: I seem to be getting this error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @James: Huh, okay, I guess I never ran into that problem before.  Try @RHSeeger's query, it looks like a more compact version of what I did.

Comment: Right; MySQL (this is a dead giveaway) will not let you update and select from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be something along the lines for (not working code)

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(Row row : ResultSet.rows()) {
    ids.add(row.get("id_queue");
}
String sql = "UPDATE table SET status = 97 WHERE id_queue IN (" + 
             StringUtils.join(ids, ",") + 
             ")";
```

Using the [StringUtils class from Apache](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).

Obviously, since you said you don't want to convert ALL items in the ResultSet to status 97:

- You can't just have an SQL query that does the SELECT/SET at the same time (unless you can formulate in SQL what the additional criteria are), and
- You'll need up modify the for loop to select out only the rows you actually want to modify

For completeness sake, the following would do the update (if you wanted to modify all rows) with pure SQL

```
UPDATE table SET status = 97
WHERE status IN (0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the error you need to give the SELECT statment an alias:
try this:
UPDATE table SET status = 97 WHERE id_queue IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id_queue
                                                FROM table
                                                WHERE status IN(0,2)) MyResult)
MyResult is an alias to the select query